# Get Response Code and Response Body ina a single request using Http-request

Tags: java, android, http-request

I am using the library http-request, from https://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request

I need to make a GET request to server and get response code **and** response body separately, given a request.

How can I do that using this lib?

There is only examples retrieving one of them, like :

```
String response = HttpRequest.get("http://google.com").body();
System.out.println("Response was: " + response);
```

and

```
int response = HttpRequest.get("http://google.com").code();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store the [`HttpRequest`](http://kevinsawicki.github.io/http-request/apidocs/index.html) object in a variable

```
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.get("http://google.com");
```

Invoke what you need

```
request.body();
request.code();
```

(It's weird to get the response body on a request object...I don't like this library.)

Comment: And it is weird too that the body of the response would be a String as the generic case.